# Configure Qt Creator to work with CDB

Tags: qt-creator, windbg

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Qt Creator to work with CDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318691/how-to-get-qt-creator-to-work-with-cdb)

I am trying to use Cdb with Qt Creator. I don't know what Qt Creator needs for its Symbol paths or Source Paths and I can't seem to find any documentation that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Install the microsoft SDK for windows 7 (version 7.1 or later) and check the box for debugging tools for windows.  Make sure you selected the msvc version of Qt, not mingw.  As long as you have the debugging tools for windows installed the next time you go to debug your application it will prompt you to set up symbol server- click yes and then you are all set.