# MSVC QT Creator - How to setup CDB correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, windbg

So I re installed my system and I am having huge problems with the MSVC debbugging. I can compile my application no problem. I have followed the instructions for [QT creator setting up debugging with CDB](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-debugger-engines.html) on Windows 7.

1. I installed MS Visual Studio 2010 and updates
2. I uninstalled 2010 C++ runtimes.
3. I installed the Windows debugging tools and SDK.
4. I also re-updated 2010 runtimes.

After all this I now have the CDB debugger.

```
C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\cdb.exe
```

In QT it auto detects the cdb.exe, this is what my kit looks like.

[image: QT Settings]

When trying to run a debug session it simply starts and quits.

```
Debugging starts
Debugging has finished
```

Comment: I honestly don't know if this an issue or not, but you appear to have the compiler configured to produce a 32 bit program and the debugger configured to use the 64 bit cdb.

Comment: @Michael Burr the installer page http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx says it should work for both, I cannot find a 32 bit version.

Comment: Download page for Debugging Tools for Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx Make sure to restart Qt Creator after installing, then it auto-detects.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Qt Creator to work with CDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5318691/how-to-get-qt-creator-to-work-with-cdb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The anwser is kind of silly, when you install QT creator you need to create at least one project first without anything setup. If you import a project without doing this first everything will fail. So the exact steps I took to get this to work are....

1) I installed VS 2010

2) Update VS 2010 to SP1

3) Update Windows and .NET

4) uninstall 2010 C++ redistributables 1.4 or newer

5) install Windows debugging tools and SDK for Windows 7

6) install QT libs

7) install QT creator

8) create C++ code snippet project

9) setup Compiler and Debbuger with CDB 64 bit

The 64 Bit CDB works in 32 bit mode as well.

Comment: Yes! Yes!! Yes!!! This works!! This totally works!!! =) =) =)
Thank you man, for the wierd but a working solutions!
All hail Rreeves!!

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem, it turns out it was not set to the x64 version. So basically: Tools->Options->Kits->Qt 5.x.x->Debugger and set it to the one ending with "x64\cdb.exe"